# Calculate half life of esters

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, applications, chemistry

I'm trying to calculate the level of testosterone released from different testosterone esters.
Here are some graphs of testosterone levels after single injections of 250mg of each ester.

Testo U 
http://postimg.org/image/lgbdkvxj7/

Testo B
http://s15.postimg.org/71alt4yyz/testob.jpg

Each ester have a specific half life.
e.g. testo e have an half life of 4.5 days.
testo b 29.5
testo u 20.9

After an injection of an ester, there will be a specific amount in your body.
say 250mg.

Those 250mg will follow a normal half life curve for that ester.
And I know how to calculate that. 
However, when the ester is reduced, the testosterone bound to it will be released.

So over time , more testo will be released from the ester, and the testosterone itself have some sort of half life I assume.

Not doing drugs here ;) working on a medical app.

(sorry for the homework tag but I have no clue what this goes under..)

Comment: Sounds like you want a coupled system of ordinary differential equations.

Comment: Why not migrate to chemistry.se???  In any case, see [this link](http://voh.chem.ucla.edu/vohtar/spring05/classes/156/pdf/COMPLEX%20REACTIONS_2005_2.pdf) page 12 of the PDF is the set of ODEs (rather the solutions thereto) that you are looking for.

Comment: @bobthechemist: page 12 contains the solutions of the coupled, reversible rate equations.  Given what is going on here (where I do not see reversibility, but I could be wrong), I think the relevant equation is Eq. (8) on Page 6.

Comment: @RonGordon You are right.  I am interpreting the OP's statement "when the ester is reduced, the testosterone bound to it will be released" as a reversible process and dependent on both the concentration of free and unbound testosterone.

Comment: So if I have the A(t) formula, and A0 (start value of A?) what do I need to do to get B(t) ?  #math-impaired