# Calculate terminal half life and build up

Tags: chemistry

Trying to solve this from a different approach now. 
started out here [Calculate half life of esters](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/441172/calculate-half-life-of-esters)

Is there a way to find a function that fits the graph below?

[image: Terminal halflife of testosterone-u]

There are a few criterions.
The area of the graph must be A
The peak of the graph must be at X (7-8 in the image)
The halflife after the peak must be H

The area in this case is the amount of testosterone, or rather the injected dose.
The peak is when the compound is fully absorbed.

y = f(A,X,H, t)

Is this possible?

My math skills are way too limited here

Comment: What you call "half life" is used in relation with some radioactive elements which, I believe, is not your thing here, so what do you call "half life" to? The mean value of the function over the given interval? Which btw I again ask: is it $\,[0,56]\;$ or something else?

Comment: It's "terminal half life" - "Terminal plasma half-life is the time required to divide the plasma
concentration by two after reaching pseudo-equilibrium" .. so in this case, from day 7 and forward.. serum levels have halved here from day 7 to day 35ish . so terminal halflife here is 28 days

Comment: http://www.fvet.uba.ar/equinos/8313/half-life.pdf  contains some math for it, sadly , I don't understand anything of it :-(

Comment: Any reaction to the answer below? Nearly two years should suffice to meditate on it, no?

Answer (score 1):

A first idea is to try to fit a gamma function, in your case $f(x)=sx\mathrm e^{-x/m}$. The slope at the origin is $s$, the maximum is at $x=m$ and its value is $sm/\mathrm e$.

A caveat though: which parameters of the curve are important to you is not quite clear from your question but a general  principle is that the more characteristics of the curve are imposed the more parameters are needed. In the present case, slope at the origin + location of the maximum + maximal height + area under the curve would a priori need four parameters (and the gamma family above is described by only two).